# date and time notification not firing in android

Tags: android, notifications

Hi in my application i designed application with date and time i want to fire the notification on particular time and date.

Now My problem if i changed the system date also notification firing i don't want like that based on current date and system date i want to fire the notification.

Can anyone please help me how to solve the issue

**MyView class**

```
public class MyView extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
     Button btn;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
         Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();


           firingCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
            firingCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
            firingCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 14);


            Calendar firingCal1 = Calendar.getInstance();


               firingCal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
                firingCal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
                firingCal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);




        // MyView is my current Activity, and AlarmReceiver is the
        // BoradCastReceiver
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyView.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyView.this,
                0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        /*
         * The following sets the Alarm in the specific time by getting the long
         * value of the alarm date time which is in calendar object by calling
         * the getTimeInMillis(). Since Alarm supports only long value , we're
         * using this method.
         */

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firingCal1.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Thanks in adavance.

**Updated code**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
        /* Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();


           firingCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
            firingCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
            firingCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 14);


            Calendar firingCal1 = Calendar.getInstance();


               firingCal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
                firingCal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
                firingCal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                */
        String input = "Sat Feb 17 2015";
        Date date = null;
        try {

            date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //What ever might be your format
        long milliseconds = date.getTime();
        long millisecondsFromNow = milliseconds - (new Date()).getTime();
        new CountDownTimer(millisecondsFromNow , 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             }

             public void onFinish() {
                //It's your date. Do your stuff here.
             }
          }.start();

        // MyView is my current Activity, and AlarmReceiver is the
        // BoradCastReceiver
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyView.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyView.this,
                0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        /*
         * The following sets the Alarm in the specific time by getting the long
         * value of the alarm date time which is in calendar object by calling
         * the getTimeInMillis(). Since Alarm supports only long value , we're
         * using this method.
         */

        /*alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firingCal1.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `CountDownTimer` class. It should solve your problem.

Comment: i don't want to set date and time i want to set some few dates if that day coming means i want to fire the notification

Comment: Yea, you can calculate no. of milliseconds from Current time to that that date and set a CountDownTimer.

Comment: can you please give some ex
    Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:
 [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`.
The post author will always be notified of your comment.
To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.
Learn more…

Answer (score 0):

You can use the server time or your network provider time.. below is the code to get the time from your network provider..

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);

long networkTimeOnRequest = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

And now, networkTimeOnRequest will hold the exact network time and you use this to compare with the date/time you specify.

Comment: If you use this, it only gives you timestamp of "When the last location was fetched using Network Provider." Not Current timestamp.

Comment: In My code what i did wrong
    Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:
 [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`.
The post author will always be notified of your comment.
To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.
Learn more…

Comment: @user3640092 your code is fine but it only checks device's time. So if user manually changes date/time, it fails to work.

Comment: hey, the AlarmManager will fire the alarm based on the device timing.. So if you want to fire the alarm based on fixed time, then you should take the server time or network time.. To get server time, you need internet connection.. Hence I gave you a code to fetch the network time, which is more or less gives you approximately correct time.. and now since you need to fire the alarm based on a fixed time, you need to run a background service and then check whether the network / server time is equal to the alarm time you set..

Comment: and to do so.. create a background service.. look at the link for an example : http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/introduction-to-services-in-android.html  .. in the service you can periodically check for the network time.. and when network time and the alarm time matches or if the difference is significant enough to fire the alarm, then try firing the alarm..

Comment: siddharth can you please give some eg

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Sat Feb 17 2015";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input); //What ever might be your format

long milliseconds = date.getTime();
long millisecondsFromNow = milliseconds - (new Date()).getTime();
                                          //Instead of new Date() you can get your server time here.
```

And set timer like this

```
new CountDownTimer(millisecondsFromNow , 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
        //It's your date. Do your stuff here.
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: There is no problem with your code. Only difference is if the user manually changes date/time, it fails to work. Where as count down timer doesn't fail as it only takes number of milliseconds and not related to device's time/date.

Comment: shall i remove the calendra and firingcall methods i added ur code that's all

Comment: When ever you want to set alarm. Just change that input date. and change simple date format according to your date format and it should work

Comment: where i need to set the timer

Comment: You can set it as you get millisecondsFromNow

Comment: hi seshu i added updated code it's not showing any error even iam not receiving any notifications

Comment: BTW, start a service and add this code there. CountDownTimer automatically stops on finishing Activity.

Comment: And you gave date as Feb 17 2015. How will it give you notification now?

Comment: And what do you mean by notification? Where did you add code to create notification? you have to add it in onFinish() of CountDownTimer

Comment: I am not getting can you once again you tell me please